# Tratar mensagens erros/alertas nativos do PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um mini framework pra gerar meus elementos, fazer interações js/requisições ajax e interagir com BD MySQL com base em alguns padrões.

Já estou usando ele a um bom tempo, mas estou querendo aumentar um pouco e inserir uma espécie de debugger no framework.

Um exemplo bem simples:

```
  public function mask( string $mask =  'undefined')
    {
        $this->mask = ' data-input-mask="' . $mask . '" ';
        return $this;
    }
```

Esse método fica dentro da classe responsável pela montagem do elemento `'input'`, e agrupando com os demais métodos a chamada é feita da seguinte forma:

```
$input = new \vidbModel\inputElement();

$field = $input
        ->type('text')
        ->field('cpf')
        ->mask('cpf')
        ->name('cpf')
        ->validator('cpf')
        ->value(null)
        ->input(0);
```

Nesse exemplo, caso eu chame o método e insira uma array no iniciador `->mask`, terei a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to vidbModel\inputElement::mask() must be of the type string, array given, called in /opt/lampp/htdocs/VIDB/docs/inputs.php on line 25 and defined in /opt/lampp/htdocs/VIDB/model/inputElement.php:78 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/VIDB/docs/inputs.php(25): vidbModel\inputElement->mask(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/VIDB/model/inputElement.php on line 78

O que eu quero fazer é o seguinte:

Receber esse erro de forma que eu possa tratar e trazer uma mensagem mais amigável a respeito do erro, converter essa mensagem nativa escrita acima em algo como:

> Erro encontrado [0001], foi passado uma array como parâmetro ao método mask(), a entrada deve ser feita unicamente com uma string, para verificar um exemplo acesse: http://sitequenaoexiste/vendor/vidb/docs/inputs.php

Dei uma pesquisada mas não encontrei nada sobre como fazer isso.

É possível tratar os erros nativos do PHP?

Existe tradução para os erros do PHP? (Apesar de que não me interessaria isso, apenas por curiosidade)

Comment: Se não estiver usando PHP 7, você pode usar a função de `set_error_handler`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na versão 7 do PHP e posteriores foi implementado o tratamento de erros  do PHP no Try, recuperando o erro com Catch

Desta forma:

```
try
{
   // seu código
}
catch (Error $e)
{
    echo "Ocorreu um erro: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Se o seu código que estiver dentro do Try apresentar erro acima, o PHP não irá parar de executar outros blocos de código, assim seu fatal erro passa a ser uma exceção.

Mais novidades do PHP7 acesse [Aqui](https://tableless.com.br/10-novidades-do-php-7/)

Em relação a tradução, creio que não é possível de maneira nativa, somente com plugins ou na "unha" mesmo. Já que as mensagens de erros são criadas por parte da equipe que desenvolve o PHP e claro que ingles pois é a lingua mais abrangente do mundo. Não vejo vantagens de traduzir os erros pois são poucos utilizados, depois que o bloco foi programado.

Espero ter ajudado.